Asking about Probability.
You are at a casino, playing game where your goal is to maximize your return from the game. The game is defined by the following rules.

pay 1 dollar to play the game.
you roll a die 100 times.
if you roll a number 1-3 you lose all of your money bet
if you roll a number 4-6 you get your bet back plus double your bet.
you may choose to end the game at any moment.

The optimal strategy is betting the entire amount won so far after each roll of the die without ending the game early. What is the expected value of your total winning after 100 rolls, assuming you follow the optimal strategy?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Havd you stated the rules correctly?  Looks like a $50-50$ bet, where you lose your dollar with probability $\frac 12$ or get $$3$ back (for a profit of $2$) also with probability $\frac 12$.  That's extremely favorable.

In any case, we need to know how many dollars you have.  If all you have is $$2$, say, then you would be unwise to bet it all on the first round, as you'll be out of the game completely with probability $\frac 12$.  Better to keep some in reserve so you can stay in the game, even if you hit a patch of bad luck.  I note that your strategy doesn't seem to make sense.  What's the first bet?  Suppose you lose the first two rounds, what's the third bet?

If you win $3^{100}$ dollars, who are you going to collect it from? There is less than $3^{30}$ dollars in the world.
